# OWA (Ordered weighted average) in TerrSet IDRISI

Tags: terrset, multi-criteria-analysis

How is OWA done in TerrSet IDRISI ?

I have used three factor maps in scale 0 to 1 of wind, distance to grid and distance to road. Factor weights of wind = 0.6, Grid = 0.3, and road= 0.1. I give order weights of 0.7, 0.2, and 0.1. The values of a pixel after OWA = 0.2822. I want to know how we reached that value using OWA? The factor map values of that pixel for Wind= 1, grid = 0.4866, and road= 0

Answer (score 0):

An example of the computation of OWA is found in the following paper:
https://www.scirp.org/html/3705.html

or

Page 235 & 236 in Jacek Malczewski's book title 'GIS and Multicriteria Decision Analysis':

https://www.amazon.ca/Multicriteria-Decision-Analysis-Jacek-Malczewski/dp/0471329444

These two resources step you through the calculations.